# Javascript validation on my form not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a form validation using JavaScript but its not working properly. Can someone please help me?

here is my code:

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var ck_name = /^[A-z]+$/;
        var ck_email = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        var ck_username = /^[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,20}$/;
        var ck_password = /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]{6,20}$/;

        function validate()
        {
            var name = document.form.name;
            var email = document.form.email;
            var username = document.form.username;
            var password = document.form.password;

            if (!ck_name.test(name)) {
             window.alert("You must enter valid Name .");
               name.focus();
               return false;
            }

            if (!ck_email.test(email)) {
                window.alert("You must enter a valid email address.");
               email.focus();
               return false;
            }

            if (!ck_username.test(username)) {
                window.alert("Your valid UserName does not contain any special char.");
                username.focus();
               return false;
            }

            if (!ck_password.test(password)) {
                window.alert("You must enter a valid Password ");
                password.focus();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }


</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form  action="#" name="form" onsubmit="return validate();">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" size="25" name="name"/></p>
    <p>E-mail:  <input type="text" size="25" name="email"/></p>
    <p>UserName: <input type="text" size="25" name="username"/></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="text" size="25" name="password"/></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: where is exactly the problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by not working properly? give us what behavior you are getting with your program.

Comment: whenever i enter name like say ketan after enter key again it says that reenter valid name.

Comment: Those text inputs need labels. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get form from document here is what you should use

```
var name = document.forms[0].name.value;
var email = document.forms[0].email.value;
var username = document.forms[0].username.value;
var password = document.forms[0].password.value;
```

This will only get html element

```
var name=document.forms[0].name
```

You need to get its value.

```
var name=document.forms[0].name.value;
```

Comment: thank you now its working properly but one more question in name field i want name like "mahesh(space)kalyankar" how should i do that coz its not taking any spaces

Comment: just allow space in regex

Comment: Like this ck_name = /^[A-z ]+$/;

Answer (score 0):

Update the js code to get the element value

```
var name = document.forms['form'].elements['name'].value;
var email = document.forms['form'].elements['email'].value;
var username = document.forms['form'].elements['username'].value;
var password = document.forms['form'].elements['password'].value;
```

Comment: one more question when input name is right but email is wrong then after clicking please enter valid email all the values are missing like valid name

Answer (score 0):

You are checking **input** elements instead you need to check their **value**.

Here is the **updated/working** code.

```
function validate() {
    var name = document.form.name;
    var email = document.form.email;
    var username = document.form.username;
    var password = document.form.password;
    if (!ck_name.test(name.value)) {
        window.alert("You must enter valid Name .");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (!ck_email.test(email.value)) {
        window.alert("You must enter a valid email address.");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (!ck_username.test(username.value)) {
        window.alert("Your valid UserName does not contain any special char.");
        username.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (!ck_password.test(password.value)) {
        window.alert("You must enter a valid Password ");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get elements' value. I just made some changes and works properly. Try this:

```js
   var ck_name = /^[A-z]+$/;
   var ck_email = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
   var ck_username = /^[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,20}$/;
   var ck_password = /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]{6,20}$/;

   function validate() {
     var name = document.form.name.value;
     var email = document.form.email.value;
     var username = document.form.username.value;
     var password = document.form.password.value;

     if (!ck_name.test(name)) {
       window.alert("You must enter valid Name .");
       name.focus();
       return false;
     }

     if (!ck_email.test(email)) {
       window.alert("You must enter a valid email address.");
       email.focus();
       return false;
     }

     if (!ck_username.test(username)) {
       window.alert("Your valid UserName does not contain any special char.");
       username.focus();
       return false;
     }

     if (!ck_password.test(password)) {
       window.alert("You must enter a valid Password ");
       password.focus();
       return false;
     }

     return true;
   }
```

```html
<form action="#" name="form" onsubmit="return validate();">
  <p>Name:
    <input type="text" size="25" name="name" />
  </p>
  <p>E-mail:
    <input type="text" size="25" name="email" />
  </p>
  <p>UserName:
    <input type="text" size="25" name="username" />
  </p>
  <p>Password:
    <input type="text" size="25" name="password" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" />
  </p>
</form>
```